# HTML table from HTTP request returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I am trying to create a chart for the HTML table I created, which stores the values retrieved from a public API.

But before I create the chart, I parse the HTML table first into a JavaScript object, and output it in the console. But it seems that it returns `null`.

Example table

```
<div>
  <div>
     <canvas id="bulkdensitychart"></canvas>
  </div>

  <table id="bulkdensity">
    <tr>
        <th>Soil Layer (meter deep)</th>
        <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0.00 m</td>
        <td id="bldfiesl1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0.05 m</td>
        <td id="bldfiesl2"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0.15 m</td>
        <td id="bldfiesl3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0.30 m</td>
        <td id="bldfiesl4"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>0.60 m</td>
        <td id="bldfiesl5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.00 m</td>
        <td id="bldfiesl6"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2.00 m</td>
        <td id="bldfiesl7"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

The script for taking values from API

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search").click(function () {
        $("#physical").show();
        let lat = $("#lat").val();
        let long = $("#long").val();
        if (lat == "" || long == "" || lat > 90 || lat < -90 || long > 180 || long < -180) {
            alert("please enter proper latitude and longitude value to get info");
            return;
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({

                type: "GET",
                url: `https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=${long}&lat=${lat}&attributes=ORCDRC,PHIHOX,PHIKCL,BLDFIE,CLYPPT,SLTPPT,SNDPPT,WWP`,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.properties.soilmask == "nodata") {
                        alert("No data found :(");
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        var bldfiesl1 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl1;
                        var bldfiesl2 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl2;
                        var bldfiesl3 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl3;
                        var bldfiesl4 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl4;
                        var bldfiesl5 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl5;
                        var bldfiesl6 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl6;
                        var bldfiesl7 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl7;
                        document.getElementById('bldfiesl1').innerHTML = bldfiesl1;
                        document.getElementById('bldfiesl2').innerHTML = bldfiesl2;
                        document.getElementById('bldfiesl3').innerHTML = bldfiesl3;
                        document.getElementById('bldfiesl4').innerHTML = bldfiesl4;
                        document.getElementById('bldfiesl5').innerHTML = bldfiesl5;
                        document.getElementById('bldfiesl6').innerHTML = bldfiesl6;
                        document.getElementById('bldfiesl7').innerHTML = bldfiesl7;
                        alert("Data updated");
                    }

                },
                function(jqXHR, exception) {
                    console.log("error");

                }
            })

        }
    })
})
```

Script for creating chart, and parsing the HTML table four output in the console

```
function BuildChart(labels, values, chartTitle) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("bulkdensitychart").getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
      labels: labels, // Our labels
      datasets: [{
        label: chartTitle, // Name the series
        data: values, // Our values
        backgroundColor: [ // Specify custom colors
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
          'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [ // Add custom color borders
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
          'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
          'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
          'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
          'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
          'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1 // Specify bar border width
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true, // Instruct chart js to respond nicely.
      maintainAspectRatio: false, // Add to prevent default behavior of full-width/height 
    }
  });
  return myChart;
}
var table = document.getElementById('bulkdensity');
var json = []; // First row needs to be headers 
var headers =[];
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
  headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
}

// Go through cells 
for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
  var tableRow = table.rows[i];
  var rowData = {};
  for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
    rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
  }

  json.push(rowData);
}

console.log(json);
```

I haven't written the code for mapping the values just yet. I want to finish this part first. How to make the values appears in the console?

Comment: There is no JSON in your question (jQuery hides the real JSON); please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: so this fall under jquery ?

Comment: My point is: it does not have anything to do with  `json`. The tag should be removed. For the rest: I read your question 3 times, and I have no idea what you are asking. Like *"it returns null value for the table"*: what is "it"? A function? Which function?

Comment: AHh i see, my mistake. Im trying to get value of the table to be available in the console, as far as my understanding for the values in the consoles for the table is in JSON

Comment: Did you read the usage description of the `json` tag, especially the part in capitals?

Comment: *"Im trying to get value of the table to be available in the console"*: so you run that *after* the answer is back from the server? Or do you run it too soon?

Comment: initially the table is empty, and awaited the values from the API to be called. Once the table is filled, then i tried to get the table to be in console, however i think the console grabs the value of the initial table which is empty

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k4u5xew6/

Here you need to take into consideration that, before completion of AJAX request. You won't be able to get the data retrieved from API inside table & it's returning "undefined" in JSON. That's why we have observed AJAX completion using "complete" method of $.ajax. And then after just used your code for retrieving & preparing JSON data, that's working fine. Check console from JSFiddle.

Reference for "complete" method of $.ajax found at: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

JS Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  getAPIData();
});

function getAPIData() {
  $.ajax({
      url: "https://rest.soilgrids.org/query?lon=72.8397202&lat=19.0010232&attributes=ORCDRC,PHIHOX,PHIKCL,BLDFIE,CLYPPT,SLTPPT,SNDPPT,WWP", 
      type: "GET", 
      dataType: "json", 
      error: function() {
          console.log("Error processing your request");
      }, 
      success: function(response) {
        var bldfiesl1 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl1;
        var bldfiesl2 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl2;
        var bldfiesl3 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl3;
        var bldfiesl4 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl4;
        var bldfiesl5 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl5;
        var bldfiesl6 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl6;
        var bldfiesl7 = response.properties.BLDFIE.M.sl7;
        document.getElementById('bldfiesl1').innerHTML = bldfiesl1;
        document.getElementById('bldfiesl2').innerHTML = bldfiesl2;
        document.getElementById('bldfiesl3').innerHTML = bldfiesl3;
        document.getElementById('bldfiesl4').innerHTML = bldfiesl4;
        document.getElementById('bldfiesl5').innerHTML = bldfiesl5;
        document.getElementById('bldfiesl6').innerHTML = bldfiesl6;
        document.getElementById('bldfiesl7').innerHTML = bldfiesl7;
      }, 
      complete: function() {
        var table = document.getElementById('bulkdensity');
        var json = []; // First row needs to be headers 
        var headers =[];
        for (var i = 0; i < table.rows[0].cells.length; i++) {
          headers[i] = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().replace(/ /gi, '');
        }

        // Go through cells 
        for (var i = 1; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
          var tableRow = table.rows[i];
          var rowData = {};
          for (var j = 0; j < tableRow.cells.length; j++) {
            rowData[headers[j]] = tableRow.cells[j].innerHTML;
          }
          json.push(rowData);
        }
        console.log("JSON DATA=", json);
      }
  });
}
```